# How do I pass a text file or a string to a Ruby script and output the result in the command line?

Tags: ruby

As an exercise to learn Ruby, I would like to create a script that will be run from the terminal. It should accept as input either a string or a text file and it should output the result of various string parsing mechanisms that I will write myself.

To get me started, would you please translate this pseudo-code into proper Ruby for me?

1. In terminal: `ruby myscript.rb` (either a string or a text file).
2. In myscript.rb: Retrieve input. Set `my_input` to the input.
3. Set `my_output` to the result of `various_string_parsing_voodoo` (done to my_input).
4. `puts my_output`

I intend to actually write the code myself, but if someone could supply me with a skeleton .rb file to send in "`Hello World`" and get "`[World] is pleased by your [hello]`" or something equally inane that'd be a great help.

Comment: a text file is a string, how are you gonna tell one from the other?

Comment: Implicitely: by checking if the given string is the path to an existing file. Explicitely: by forcing the user to pass the argument as an option (`-t` for text, `-f` for file, for instance). The first one is actually easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some key pieces:

- `ARGV` is an array containing the arguments you passed when running your script from command line.
- the `File` class contains several utilies. For example, `File.exists?(path)` returns true if the path exists, and `File.file?(path)` returns true if the path exists and is a file (not a dir).

I think this may help you quite a bit.

Comment: It did indeed. :) Thank you kindly, sir.